# Server Busy This action cannot be completed because the other program is busy

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, internet

I am using HR Block 2015 efile. Upon hitting send, I get the confirm send dialog and after hitting ok and a short interval another alert pops up with the title Server Busy.

The really bad error text reads "This action cannot be completed because the other program is busy. Choose "Switch to" to activate the busy program and correct the problem".

Hitting the Switch to button, pops open the main program menu, but there is no hint of the program it is referring to.

Not much online about this, but it appears to be a conflict within windows, security and networking. One instance was tracked to a faulty virus scanner install. I disabled all the virus scanners and firewalls, but did not clear the problem.  I also started the computer in safe mode, but got the same error.

Windows XP Home OS and a recent download of HRBlock 2015 software.  Any insights or suggestions, if you have them.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you on XP SP3? That is a requirement for your software.

Comment: yes, XP 2002 Service Pack 3

Comment: This is commonly cause by a program entering into a non-responding state, a problem like this, would require HR&Block technical support to resolve.  There is likely a way to get more verbose information from the software to determine the reason its entering this non-response state. If your hardware supports it, I suggest using a demo [Windows 7 VM](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/), and installing your software to that.